# Inverse dependencies for deletion/change

Tags: terraform

Can I get terraform to create resource A before creating resource B, while also deleting resource A before deleting resource B? In case of replacement this should be chained:
delete A, then delete B, then create A, then create B.

The problem I have is with azurerm cdn custom domains and cname records. Custom CDN domains can only be created when an according DNS record exists. The can also be removed only, if the DNS record does not exist.

The problem is reproducible with the example in the [official documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_endpoint_custom_domain)

Comment: Hard to give you an accurate answer without any terraform code ... `Is it possible` if all you want to know is that; Yes I'm sure there is a possible way that terraform is doing what you are experiencing

Comment: @HelderSepulveda: Thanks for the input. I tried to rephrase my question to make more sense.

Comment: is this related:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/is-it-possible-to-change-the-destroy-order/30303 ?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda: yes this exactly my problem.

Comment: from that discuss: the correct fix for this problem is to run `az feature register --namespace Microsoft.Cdn --name BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion` does that work for you? you can run that with a null_resource just like I showed before but use created instead of destroy

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something like that with the help of a null_resource
not quite sure how this will do in case of replacement

Here is a theoretical example:

```hcl
resource "test" "a" {
  
}

resource "test" "b" {
  depends_on = [ test.a ]
}

resource "null_resource" "delete" {
  triggers = {
    t = "abc"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "cmd to delete A"
  }

  depends_on = [ test.b ]
}
```

The `null_resource` has the `when = destroy` so the command will only run when we invoke a terraform destroy, we just need to be careful there not to create a circular reference

---

Here is another test I was just playing around with:

```hcl
resource "local_file" "a" {
  content  = "aaaa"
  filename = "${path.module}/a.txt"
}

resource "local_file" "b" {
  content  = "bbbb"
  filename = "${path.module}/b.txt"
  depends_on = [ local_file.a ]
}

resource "null_resource" "delete" {
  triggers = {
    t = "abc"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = destroy
    command = "rm a.txt; sleep 15"
  }

  depends_on = [ local_file.b ]
}
```

`apply`

```txt
local_file.a: Creating...
local_file.a: Creation complete after 0s [id=...]
local_file.b: Creating...
local_file.b: Creation complete after 0s [id=...]
null_resource.delete: Creating...
null_resource.delete: Creation complete after 0s [id=...]
```

`destroy`

```txt
null_resource.delete: Destroying... [id=...]
null_resource.delete: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.delete (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "rm a.txt; sleep 15"]
null_resource.delete: Still destroying... [id=..., 10s elapsed]
null_resource.delete: Destruction complete after 15s
local_file.b: Destroying... [id=...]
local_file.b: Destruction complete after 0s
local_file.a: Destroying... [id=...]
local_file.a: Destruction complete after 0s
```

I added the `sleep 15` to give me some time and manually verify that the file was deleted as intended, and yes it seems the order works without any hiccups, the resource `a` sees the file is no longer there and completes the destroy process without any errors